# Rails - syntax for alternative render when collection is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code and it's not working

```
$('div').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'comments/image_comment',
                                  collection: @image_comments || render html: "<strong>Not Found</strong>".html_safe) %>");
```

I also tried this

```
$('div').html("<%= escape_javascript (render (partial: 'comments/image_comment',
                                  collection: @image_comments) || render (html: "<strong>Not Found</strong>".html_safe)) %>");
```

I can't use the shorthand `render @image_comments` for some reason because when I do rails is using a partial I have named `_comments.html.erb` instead of `_image_comments.html.erb` and I don't know why.

**Error**

```
SyntaxError (/show_comments.js.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...@image_comments || render html: "<strong>Not Found</strong>"...
...                               ^
/show_comments.js.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...ot Found</strong>".html_safe) );@output_buffer.safe_append='...
```

Comment: what error getting, can u post ?

Comment: Ruby actually is sensitive to whitespace; if you're going to use parentheses in method calls don't put any space between the method name and the opening parenthesis.

Comment: Can u try this one in `show_comments.js.erb` -> `<% data = @image_comments ? j render (partial: 'comments/image_comment', collection: @image_comments) : "<strong>Not Found</strong>" %>
$('div').html(<%=  data%>);`

Comment: @7urkm3n doesn't seem to work. I get a syntax error that points to the space after `j render`

Comment: @muistooshort Removing the space after the method name gets rid of the  error, but when my collection is empty I am not getting the second part of the conditional to render.

Answer (score 0):

Do your condition in `_image_comments.html.erb` file like this:

```
<% if @image_comments %>
  ==> your current partial here
<% else %>
  <strong>Not Found</strong>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. If I am using a collection and if the collection is empty, won't rails not do anything with the partial since there are no members in the collection?

Comment: if you have anything in the collection, you will render your partial (as previously). If you don't have any, you will render "Not found". So, you will need only to call `<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/image_comments') %>`

Comment: The very bottom of this [section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) says if you have an empty collection render will return nil so that's why I thought I could use something like my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy just use either one approach.

```
<%if !@image_comments.empty?%>
    $('div').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'comments/image_comment', collection: @image_comments) %>");
<%else%>
    $('div').html("<strong>Not Found</strong>") %>");
<%end%>
```

**OR**

```
$('div').html("<%= !@image_comments.empty? ? escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/image_comment', collection: @image_comments) : '<strong>Not Found</strong>' %>");
```